# Pytorch Fully Connected Feed Forward Network for a regression problem - Gives same result for all inputs

Tags: deep-learning, regression, pytorch

I build a neural network model in Pytorch for a simple regression problem (w1x1+w2x2+w3x3 = y) where I generated 2000 records for training data with random values for x1,x2,x3 and W1=4, W2=6, W3=2. I created a test dataset of 20 records with just values for x1,x2,x3 and I was hoping to get the result for But, the model returns same value for all 20 input rows. I don't know where the issue is. Below is the code snippet.

```
inputs = df[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']]
target = df['y']
inputs = torch.tensor(inputs.values).float()
target = torch.tensor(target.values).float()

test_data = torch.tensor(test_data.values).float()

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Net,self).__init__()

    hidden1 = 10
    hidden2 = 15

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3,hidden1)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden1,hidden2)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden2,1)


  def forward(self,x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x

#instantiate the model

model = Net()
print(model)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)

model.train()

#epochs
epochs = 500


for x in range(epochs):
  #initialize the training loss to 0
  train_loss = 0
  #clear out gradients
  optimizer.zero_grad() 

  #calculate the output
  output = model(inputs)

  #calculate loss
  loss = criterion(output,target)

  #backpropagate
  loss.backward() 

  #update parameters
  optimizer.step()

  if ((x%5)==0):
    print('Training Loss after epoch {:2d} is {:2.6f}'.format(x,loss))

#set the model in evaluation mode
model.eval()

#Test the model on unseen data

test_output = model(test_data)

print(test_output)
```

Comment: Try a simple straight line model first, w1x1=y, with only a few data points -that should work OK. After that try w1x1 + w2x2 = y with only a few data points, that should also be OK. Finally, try w1x1 + w2x2 + w3x3 = y with only a few data points.

Comment: @JamesPhillips no luck. I still get the same output for a single input w1x1=y for all values

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with the smallest code that reproduces this problem for "y = (w1 * x1) + constant"  with two data points in the code. Make the title something like "PyTorch will not fit straight line to two data points".